# Angular2 - how should I parse xml into json?

Tags: json, xml, parsing, angular

I want to import RSS but I don't know how should I parse xml into json using angular2/typescript. I have seen a lot of ways to do that by using jquery but I need approve that's the best way to do it.

Can you give me any propositions about what should I use? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I saw a lot of people using google feed api to retrieve a json formatted RSS Feed.

There's a fiddle I found with Google:

http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/b8Wcz/

Here's the way he call Google API:

`$http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=50&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url));`